# Using object as a value in `react-hook-form`

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hook-form

### Description

I have a component that uses an object as a value.

I would like to use this component with `react-hook-form`

The problem is that **`react-hook-form` thinks that my object is a nested form control**

### Setup

This is just an example.

Range date picker is a common use case for such a behaviour

[Example codepen](https://codesandbox.io/s/runtime-fast-7kf9i4?file=/src/App.tsx)

The value that the component accepts:

```
type ComponentValue = {
  a: string;
  b: string;
}
```

The component:

```
const Component = ({ value, onChange }: { value: ComponentValue, onChange: (value: ComponentValue) => void }) => {
  return (
    <input value={value.a} onChange={e => onChange({ a: e.target.value, b: (Math.random() * 100 | 0).toString() }) } />
  )
}
```

Form value

```
type FormValues = {
  someField: ComponentValue;
  // other fields
};
```

Default values:

```
const defaultValues = {
  someField: {
    a: 'Default a',
    b: 'Default b'
  },
  // other fields
};
```

`useForm` usage:

```
const {
  register,
  handleSubmit,
  formState: { errors },
  control,
} = useForm<FormValues>({
  defaultValues,
});
```

### The problem

Hovering over (or trying to use) `errors` reveals the type:

```
const errors: {
  someField?: {
    a?: FieldError | undefined;
    b?: FieldError | undefined;
  } | undefined;
  // other fields
}
```

But I would it to be:

```
const errors: {
  someField?: FieldError | undefined;
  // other fields
}
```

### Summary

Can I somehow force `react-hook-form` to treat my object as a value instead of a nested form field?

Comment: RHF uses defaultValues and generic (in useForm<T>) to know the form of the inputs in the form. So it is normal that the way you write it, it expects to have 2 string inputs, which will be saved as someField.a and someField.b.

What do you really want to do? I suggest to add the implementation of the React component.

Comment: I added component's code

Comment: You wand to interface your controlled component with RHF. See https://react-hook-form.com/get-started#IntegratingControlledInputs

Comment: @pom421'm already doing this, but didn't include it because the issue appears before I even use it. RHF just can't accept objects as values probably.

Comment: It can't because RHF is just a wrapper on form. You can just use inputs as HTML input. So at the end, you only can have input for text, number or date. Wrap those inputs in JS object is up to you. In your case, only a is a real input, a regular text. b is only a computed data to display.

Comment: What if I wanted a double date picker for example (date range)? Pretty common use

Comment: I guess you could work around this by stringifying the object value when passing it to the RHF? However, that makes it hard to type the form value + could add complexity for things like validation. I think it would be easier to get around it to just write some logic to process the error object and present any errors in a good way.

Answer (score 7):

If you want to combine 2 inputs in a same component, you can try the approach with a controller.

```
export default function App() {
  const { control, handleSubmit, watch } = useForm({
    defaultValues: {
      travel: {
        from: "paris",
        to: "london"
      }
    }
  });

  const onSubmit = (data) => {
    console.log("dans onSubmit", JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
  };

  return (
    <>
      <h1>Travel</h1>

      <form
        onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}
        style={{ display: "flex", flexDirection: "column", maxWidth: 600 }}
        noValidate
      >
        <TravelPicker control={control} />

        <input type="submit" />
        <pre>{JSON.stringify(watch(), null, 2)}</pre>
      </form>
    </>
  );
```

The component have a control props, to be able to register the 2 inputs :

```
const TravelPicker = ({ control }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <label>
        From
        <Controller
          name="travel.from"
          control={control}
          render={({ field: { onChange, value, name } }) => (
            <input name={name} value={value} onChange={(e) => onChange(e)} />
          )}
        />
      </label>
      <label>
        To
        <Controller
          name="travel.to"
          control={control}
          render={({ field: { onChange, value, name } }) => (
            <input name={name} value={value} onChange={(e) => onChange(e)} />
          )}
        />
      </label>
    </>
  );
};
```

The errors object has then the same structure as the form inputs.

See this [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/travel-picker-xmglpk?file=/pages/index.tsx) for a functional exemple.

The createor of RHF seems to indicate [here](https://github.com/react-hook-form/react-hook-form/discussions/2363#discussioncomment-42298) that you can also have only one component for 2 inputs.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `setValue` and `setError` like below:

```
const {setValue, setError} = useForm();

// ... some where in your form
<input 
  type = "text"
  name = "from"
  onChange = {
    (event) => {
      const value = event.target.value;
      if(value === ""){
        setError("from", "This field is required");
      }else{
        setValue(`from[0]`, {
          "otherProperty" : "otherValue",
          "from_value": value, // this is your input value
        });
      }
    }
  }
/>
```

**Probably you would be iterating through an array. change static 0 with your index in `setValue`** If not you may use object syntax like below:

```
//....
setValue(`from.your_property_name`, {
    "otherProperty" : "otherValue",
    "from_value": value, // this is your input value
});

// ....
```

This won't cause re-render of component.

More info in [doc](https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform/setvalue)

NOTE: Please be respectful when commenting.